# How can I use nested for loops in Python-3.x to print from a text file one line at a time, x number of cycles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

I am attempting to print from a text file one line at a time, however many cycles I require. I am stuck here:

```
    def do():
        i = 0
        for i in range(int(mlt)):
            file = open('/some/dir/text.txt' , 'r')
            for line in file:
                linenumber = file.readline()
                time.sleep(1)
                print(linenumber)

    mlt = input('number of cycles')
    do()
```

This outputs to:

```
    line2

    line4

    line6

    line8

    line10

    line2

    line4
    ....
```

When I require:

```
    line1

    line2

    line3

    line4

    line5

    line6

    line7

    line8

    line9

    line10

    line1

    line2

    line3
    ...
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain to me what it is I am doing wrong.

Comment: print adds a carriage return.  try print(linenumber.strip('\n')) or ('\r') depending on what sort of crs your system is using.

Answer (score 1):

`for line in file:` and `linenumber = file.readline()` are doing the same thing which is why you are getting every second line.  Try the following:

```
     for line in file:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the file with `for line in file:`, but then in each iteration you grab the *next* line with `readline()`, resulting in printing every other line. The double-spacing is because `print()` has a default end of a newline. To fix this, simply print every line in the file with no extra characters:

```
def do(num):
    for i in range(num):
        with open('/some/dir/text.txt' , 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                time.sleep(1)
                print(line, end='')

mlt = input('number of cycles')
do(int(mlt))
```

I've also refactored your code a bit so the function takes an argument representing the number of times it should loop.